# Winform character spacing

Tags: c#, winforms, kerning

I am trying to use Graphics.DrawString and TextRenderer.DrawText to laydown on a fixed rectangle some strings with variable number of characters.

However, even using the GDI+ wrapping methods I am not satisfied with result: I would need to control the font kerning (or string character spacing) to give a chance to pack high number of characters strings.

I read about FontStretches but I do not know how to use in winform. Another method is Typography.SetKerning but again I am blank about using it.

Can someone help?!

Round 2:
I know it could be hard, Win32 API has a freetype support which could be the solution to issue.
Practically my aim is to do something similar to "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582545/kerning-problems-when-drawing-text-character-by-character", in .NET. Notice that I am working on pre-formed string of arabic language, not user character imput.
My problem is: 
(1) identify which library has the wanted kerning function (most probably gdi32.dll), (2) build a c# safe environment to deal with dll calls, (3) implement a call to dll that works in c#.

Can someone help?

Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com), its quite easy to find out which does what, and how to use it.

The method [Typography.SetKerning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.typography.setkerning%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is an WPF-only thing, so you won't be able to use it in WinForms.

A quick Google found [this](http://blog.stevex.net/rendering-text-using-the-net-framework/) article, which shows us how to modify kerning values to GDI text.

Comment: Thanks @freedomspace, i know bob.stevex blog because it gives me hangs and disconnections (from china?), unfortunately i cannot reach the page.

Comment: @cmd, here ( http://img854.imageshack.us/img854/8485/20110727064945.png ) is a screenshot of the linked web page.